# How to update documents in Sharepoint 2010 via Linux?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have some engineers in our company that work primarily on Linux (Ubuntu).  They need the ability to update documents in a document library on our MOSS 2010 site.  They can check out the documents and download a copy of the document via Firefox/Chrome, but there is no way to update the document prior to or during the check in process.  The only option is to upload the revised document as a seperate new document.

Can anyone help?

** EDIT **  I believe I have it working by following the following steps.  What is confusing to me is why SP didn't just have an 'Upload Updated File' button on the check in dialog.

1. check out the document (req'd in our library).
2. Download a copy of the doc to local filesystem
3. Edit document on local filesystem
4. In Sharepoint ribbon, select 'Upload Document' making sure that 'Overwrite existing files' is checked.  Select updated file on local filesystem.
5. Doc will be updated as long as filenames match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, works fine for me and several coworkers of mine from MacOS and Linux using Mozilla, Safari and Chrome.

Can you describe the problem a bit more? Yes you have to manually upload the document, buy not as a "seperate new document".

Comment: Cristoph......I think I have it working.  I've updated my question with the steps I followed.  Can you verify if that is the same general process you and your team have followed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the video demonstrating Open->Edit->Update on Linux. It contains payed product but may be helpful for some people. It is recorded on Mint, but works on Ubuntu 14+, Kubuntu and other Debian flavors.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZUHsJWLu50